# Having problem uninstalling f.lux from pop!_os, how do I uninstall f.lux completely?

Tags: uninstall

I'm using pop!_os

I installed f.lux, and I uninstalled flux (at least fluxgui..)

I was going to try Redshift. I installed Redshift and uninstalled Redshift (as it wouldn't open and my screen began to flick between tint and no-tint).

My screen is still flicking between tint and no-tint.

Any advice?

I suspect flux is still running, just the gui is uninstalled (it wasn't opening anyway), but I'm not sure how to get rid of it.. any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to add f.lux, flux and pop!_os as tags; however, I don't have enough reputation, sorry.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted a file called 'fluxgui.desktop' I now no longer have a screen tint.

I'm still irked.

I tried to find a way of using flux from the terminal, apparently it isn't possible.